# Text becomes very slightly blurry after applying z-index in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, react-redux

I have elements with text on page. I have noticed that text is actually very slightly blurry in Chrome in comparison to Firefox. When I removed z-index from the element text becomes sharper. 
How can I make text sharp without removing z-indexes.

Here is an HTML code:

```
<div class="navigation navigation-fixed">
    <div class="navigation-infouser">
    <a href="/bohdan.andriyiv"><span>Bohdan Andriyiv</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is CSS for this div:

```
.navigation-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 52px;
    z-index: 11; //when removed text becomes sharper
```

Comment: Since you are using positions, make sure there is no any other elements go over it

Comment: There is no other element going over text. It just when I disable z-index or make it 0 or smaller then 0 blurriness disappears.

Comment: the z-index itself has no effect on the text on any browser, so it is for sure something different happening after changing the z-index, but not the z-index itself, may be a js or another element or the element position on the screen, by the way if there is nothing showing over your element why you are using z-index anyway?

Comment: My element with text is a floating header, similar to the the one here on Stackoverflow. The text is in the left corner of the header. In the center of screen we have stream of posts that go beneath header when we scroll down the page. The text in the left corner of the header is slightly blur. When I make z-index of header 0 the text becomes sharp, but then posts are going over the header.

Comment: I have also just noticed that when I change z-index the element changes not only its z-position (deepness),  but also it's location (x, y position). Do you know how that can happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to fixed-position elements that are behind relative-positioned elements.

What I mean that you probably have another element that is above and "hiding" your element when you have the z-index attribute set, when you remove it the text becomes sharper because now the element is above other one.

Comment: No, this is not possible in my case. The text in my case is a child element of the element for which I change z-index. And anyway I remove/decrease z-index (putting the element deeper not higher).

Comment: The only code I can post is already in the question. This is a really strange situation so far I found this artcile [http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/gpu-text-rendering-in-webkit](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/gpu-text-rendering-in-webkit), which could have explained this situation,  but it says nothing about z-indexes.